# How to get app Incremental deployment to kubernetes

Tags: maven, jenkins, kubernetes

I tried to setup Continuous Deployment using jenkins for own microservice project which is organized as multi-module maven project (each submodule representing a micro service). I use "Incremental build - only build changed modules" in jenkins to avoid unnessesary building, and then use docker-maven-plugin to build docker image. However, how could I do to only redeploy changed images to kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local docker image registry.
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

You can then push the development images to this registry as a build step and make your kubernetes containers use this registry.

After you are ready, push the image to your production image registry and adjust container manifests to use proper registry.

More info on private registry server: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I havent described my question clearly. For example, I created a maven project A which has two submodule A1 and A2. if i commit a change in A1, it will trigger a ci workflow of project A in jenkins, and then maven will do Incremental build and create a new docker image of  A1.  note that A2 has no change. However is there a easy way to know which docker image has changed and need to be redeployed to my kubernetes cluster?

Comment: How do you deploy these images to cluster now?

Comment: In my dev environment, I can execute comman "kubectl create " or "kubectl apply" manually to deploy my pods and services. But in CI/CD workflow, I need them to be deployed or redeployed automatically according to the change committed into git repository.

Comment: I guess it's more of a jenkins question, in which I am not an expert :/. But maybe you can store hashes of previous images on in your jenkins artifacts somewhere, compare it to newest images in a custom build step and if they don't match - apply or create the pod?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Kubernetes does not provide proper solution for this. But there are few workarounds mentioned [here]: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664

I like this one 'Fake a change to the Deployment by changing something other than the image'. We can do it in this way :

Define environment variable say "TIMESTAMP" and any value to it in deployment manifest. In CI\CD pipeline we set the value to current timestamp and then pass this updated manifest to 'kubectl apply'. This way, we are faking a change and kubernetes will pull the latest image and deploy to the cluster. Please make sure that 'imagePullPolicy : always' is set.